# How do I clean up this mess using content_tags?

Tags: formatting, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this helper method that I can't seem to clean up with `content_tag` in `Rails 3.1`

```
def site_address(site)
    html = '<address>'    
    html += site.address1 if site.address1.present?
    html += tag(:br) + site.address2 if site.address2.present?
    html += tag(:br) + site.city + ', ' if site.city.present?
    html += site.state.statecode if site.state.present?
    html += ' ' + site.zipcode if site.zipcode.present?
    html += '</address>'

    html.html_safe
end
```

If I try using `content_tag(:address) do....` and then put the content in the block, it just escapes my `<br />` tags.

Also notice there is a lot of `if.present?` logic because the table can have a bunch of null values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered moving this logic into a partial? Also, you should be using the new `#presence` method.

First, the method:

```
def site_address(site)
  address = [
    site.address1.presence,
    site.address2.presence
  ].compact

  location = ""
  location << site.city << ", " if site.city.present?
  location << site.state.statecode if site.state.present?
  location << site.zipcode if site.zipcode.present?

  render :partial => "shared/site_address",
         :locals => { :address_lines => address, :location => location }
end
```

Then, the partial:

```
<address>
  <% address_lines.each do |line| %>
    <%= line %><br>
  <% end %>
  <%= location %>
</address>
```

In general, using `html_safe` in a helper is a hint that you might be going overboard with HTML logic in your helper, and that it might a good idea to fall back on the template engine, which lets you more easily mix static and dynamic content with good default XSS-safe semantics.

**Note**: If `address1`, `address2`, etc. are actually `nil`, and not possibly an empty String (I suspect this is true about site.state, at least), you don't need to use `present` at all. Just say `if site.state` and call it a day. The `present` and `presence` methods simply treat empty values as if they were `nil` for the purpose of conditionals.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't even know about the presence method.